# How to block HTTP requests to an Azure webapp, except those from a specific other Azure service

Tags: azure, web-applications

My Azure setup involves two web apps and a PostgreSQL server. One of the web apps is a Node frontend, which should be available to the public. The other is a Python backend, which receives requests from the Node app and communicates with the Postgres database. The Python app contains HTTP endpoints that should not be available for anyone to access.

What is the recommended approach to protecting this Python app from unwanted traffic? Should I be blocking traffic outright through some sort of Azure configuration, or simply authenticating my HTTP requests?

I've tried only allowing the outbound IPs of the Node app to communicate with the Python app, via the Azure configuration. However, this seems to have left the Python app unable to communicate with the database, and additionally I can't even SSH or view its logs with this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your requirements are.  If cost is no option, one way to protect the python app is to put it on an App Service Environment (ASE).  This is an isolated instance of Azure Web Apps that you can protect behind an [Internal Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info).  This solution will give you more security as you can enable a Network Security Group to block out Internet traffic and you could setup your Node App to communicate with your VNet with a VPN.  This approach is also one of the more expensive approaches for a PaaS Web App.

Other options include setting up your "back-end" python as IaaS (but then you have to manage the updates), or you can use an App Gateway or 3rd party WAF device like KEMP (they have a 200 MBps device that is free) to protect you app.

Finally you can look at a scalability design where you put a queue or some other intermediary between your two web apps.  This will allow for independent scaling and give you the opportunity to lock-down the Python app to only accept messages from the queue, not your front-end.  A sample arch can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/scalable-web-app) (you can sub the function in this arch for your python app)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. I think the ASE approach may end up too expensive for my usage, so I'm going to look into using an App Gateway to shield it.